# How to make single property in array reactive when using `ref` instead of `reactive`?

Tags: vue.js, reactive, ref, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

I have a component that displays rows of data which I want to toggle to show or hide details. This is how this should look:
[image: working version]

This is done by making the mapping the data to a new array and adding a `opened` property. Full working code:

```js
<script setup>
import { defineProps, reactive } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps({
  data: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  },
  dataKey: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const rows = reactive(props.data.map(value => {
  return {
    value,
    opened: false,
  };
}));

function toggleDetails(row) {
  row.opened = !row.opened;
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <template v-for="row in rows" :key="row.value[dataKey]">
      <div>
        <!-- Toggle Details -->
        <a @click.prevent="() => toggleDetails(row)">
          {{ row.value.key }}: {{ row.opened ? 'Hide' : 'Show' }} details
        </a>

        <!-- Details -->
        <div v-if="row.opened" style="border: 1px solid #ccc">
          <div>opened: <pre>{{ row.opened }}</pre></div>
          <div>value: </div>
          <pre>{{ row.value }}</pre>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

However, I do not want to make the Array deeply reactive, so i tried working with `ref` to only make `opened` reactive:

```js
const rows = props.data.map(value => {
  return {
    value,
    opened: ref(false),
  };
});

function toggleDetails(row) {
  row.opened.value = !row.opened.value;
}
```

The property `opened` is now fully reactive, but the toggle doesn't work anymore:

[image: not working version]

How can I make this toggle work without making the entire value reactive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to come from Vue replacing the ref with its value.

When `row.opened` is a ref initialized as `ref(false)`, a template expression like this:

```
{{ row.opened ? 'Hide' : 'Show' }}
```

seems to be interpreted as (literally)

```
{{ false ? 'Hide' : 'Show' }}
```

and not as expected as (figuratively):

```
{{ row.opened.value ? 'Hide' : 'Show' }}
```

But if I write it as above (with the `.value`), it works.

Same with the `if`, it works if I do:

```
<div v-if="row.opened.value">
```

It is interesting that the behavior occurs in `v-if` and ternaries, but not on direct access, i.e. `{{ rows[0].opened }}` is reactive but `{{ rows[0].opened ? "true" : "false" }}` is not. This seems to be an issue with Vue's expression parser. There is a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65773395/vue-3-composition-api-array-of-refs-doesnt-work).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I found more information through the link you sent and found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73191385/5122964. Thank you

Comment: @AdriaanMeuris Very interesting. "It is because they want to" - hard to argue with that lol. Still confusing why `{{ rows[0].opened }}` works, my guess is that it uses `toString()` of the ref, which itself is reactive. Anyway, I learned something today. Thank you!